# Equation of line of locus.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the equation of the locus of a point whose distance from the point (2, -2) is equal to its distance from the line x-y=0. I can't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to [Eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_%28mathematics%29).

Let the point be $P \equiv (x, y)$.

Distance of P from $(2, 2)$ is $\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2} $ (1)

Distance of a point $(x_1, y_1)$ from a line $ax+by+c=0$ is $\left|\dfrac{ax_1+by_1+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right|$

So distance of P from $x-y = 0$ is $\left|\dfrac{x-y}{\sqrt2}\right|$. (2)

Now, (1) and (2) are equal.

Therefore, $$\begin{align}\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2} =\left|\dfrac{x-y}{\sqrt2}\right| \\(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 = \dfrac{(x-y)^2}{2}\end{align}$$

Can you simplify after this?

Comment: i can but what did we do in the 3rd line ? after distance from P.

Comment: Distance between $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ is $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2}$. Distance between a point $(x_1, y_1)$ and line $ax+by+c = 0$ is $\left|\dfrac{ax_1+by_1+c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right|$. Rest is just substitution and algebra.

Comment: how did you substitute in $ ax_1 + by_1 +c $ ?

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/q/85761/66212

Comment: Ok I understand Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to find [something like this](http://www.nwcsd.k12.ny.us/cms/lib/NY19000569/Centricity/Domain/139/9-27_compound_locus_day_1.pdf)

If you need help solving this, just comment below, and I can work it out.

Comment: i saw this but couldn't understand what it said.