# Is this solution legal?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Let $M(1,-1)$ be a point in a plane. Find its distance from a line given by $x+2y-4=0$.

Later on I found a formula: 
$$d=\frac{\left | Ax_{0}+Bx_{0}+C  \right | }{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

But I did it somehow without using it. Like this:

The distance between a point $M$ and a line $p:\; y=-\frac{1}{2}x+2$ is a segment of another line that is perpendicular to $p$, let's mark it as $q$, which has the property that $M\in q$.
From $M\in q$ we have: $$y+1=k(x-1) \Rightarrow q:\;\; y=kx-(k+1)$$
From $p\perp q$ we have:  $$k_{1}k_{2}=-1 \; \Rightarrow \; -\frac{1}{2}k_{2}=-1  \; \Rightarrow \; k_{2}=2$$    $$q: \;\; y=2x-3$$
Now, we obtain a point of intersection $N$ between $p$ and $q$ which is $N(2,1)$.
And now we find the distance between points $M(1,-1)$ and $N$.
$$d=\sqrt{(x_{2}-x_{1})^2+(y_{2}-y_{1})^2}=\sqrt{1^2+2^2} \;\; \Rightarrow \;\; d=\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: Nicely done!  Looks correct, you should feel good about taking the time to understand the problem rather than blindly using a formula.  Notice that your method reveals not just the distance but also the closest point.

Comment: You answered your own question in a nice way!!

Comment: If you apply your method for a general line and external point, you will now know one way to derive the formula you mention.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner That's what I'm doing right now, it's cool xd

Comment: Wonderful!  "The mathematician's impulse is to generalize."

Comment: There exist no *illegal* solutions (at least i've never heard of any).

Answer (score 1):

*This is just an answer to get your question formally answered.*

Yes, it is.

Since @Valerin has already confirmed that you have answered it "*in a nice way*" [in the body of the question itself], I just add to @colormegone's comment ("*If you apply your method for a general line and external point, you will now know one way to derive the formula you mention.*") the following general method (copied from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85767/752) of mine):

The distance $d$ between a point $P_1(x_{1},y_{1})$ and a line $r$ whose
equation is $Ax+By+C=0$ can be derived algebraically  as follows:

*i)* Find the equation of the straight line $s$ passing through $P_1$ and which is orthogonal to $r$. Call $P_2$ the intersecting point of $r$ and $s$.

*ii)* Find the co-ordinates of $P_2(x_{2},y_{2})$.

*iii)* Find the distance from $P_1$ to $P_2$. This distance is $d$.

Comment: See also e.g. all the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/85761/752) question.