# Finding the equation of the circle with given radius tangent to lines $y=x$ and $y=2x$ using pencils of circles.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, circles

> Find the equation of the circle with radius $3$ whose center lies in the first quadrant and is tangent both to the lines $y=x$ and $y=2x$

My solution is as follows

Let $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ be the points of contact with resp. tangents $y=2x$ and $y=x$:

The two families of circles are

${x^2} - 2x{x_1} + {x_1}^2 + {y^2} - 2y{y_1} + {y_1}^2 + L\left( {y - 2x} \right) = 0 \Rightarrow \\{x^2} + {y^2} - 2x\left( {{x_1} + L} \right) - 2y\left( {{y_1} - \frac{L}{2}} \right) + {x_1}^2 + {y_1}^2 = 0$

&

${x^2} - 2x{x_2} + {x_2}^2 + {y^2} - 2y{y_2} + {y_2}^2 + M\left( {y - x} \right) = 0 \Rightarrow \\{x^2} + {y^2} - 2x\left( {{x_2} + \frac{M}{2}} \right) - 2y\left( {{y_2} - \frac{M}{2}} \right) + {x_2}^2 + {y_2}^2 = 0$

Both circles are similar, how do we equate the values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two given lines that are not parallel to each other, the angle bisector is given by

$ \displaystyle \frac{Ax+By+C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} = \pm \frac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

where the given lines are $Ax + By + C =0$ and $ax + by + c =0$

We have lines $y-2x = 0$ and $y-x = 0$ that intersect at the origin.

$ \displaystyle \frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}} = \pm \frac{y-2x}{\sqrt{5}}$

For internal bisector,

$ \displaystyle \frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}} = - \frac{y-2x}{\sqrt{5}}$

$\implies \displaystyle y = \frac{2\sqrt2+\sqrt5}{\sqrt2+\sqrt5} x$

$\displaystyle y = \frac{1+\sqrt{10}}{3} x$

As the center of the circle is on this line, its coordinates can be written as $(x_0, \frac{1+\sqrt{10}}{3} x_0)$.

Now perpendicular distance to $y - x = 0$ from the center is $3$.

$ \displaystyle \frac{|\frac{1+\sqrt{10}}{3} x_0 - x_0|}{\sqrt2} = 3$

Solving $ \displaystyle x_0 = \frac{9\sqrt2}{\sqrt{10}-2} = 3 (\sqrt5+\sqrt2), y_0 = 3 (\sqrt5+2\sqrt2)$

And equation of circle is $(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = 9$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Fig. 1: (Some circles of) the pencil of circles $P_1$ in blue, and $P_2$ in red (notations of (1)). Their common circle, the one we want, is in black. Point-circles $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are materialized by small stars.*

I understand your method in the following way. You consider two **linear pencils of circles** each one generated by a "point-circle" [...] and a straight line:

$$\begin{cases}[(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2]+L(y-2x)&=&0&\text{pencil} \ P_1\\
[(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2]+M(y-x)&=&0&\text{pencil} \ P_2\end{cases} \tag{1}$$

and you want to find the common circle to the two pencils ; the problem you meet is that, by identification of like coefficients,

$$\begin{cases}x_1 + L&=&x_2+\frac{M}{2}\\y_1 - \frac{L}{2}&=&y_2 - \frac{M}{2}\\x_1^2 + y_1^2&=&x_2^2 + y_2^2\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

you have 3 equations with 6 unknowns...

1. In fact you should use only 4 unknowns because $y_1=2x_1$ and $y_2=x_2$.
2. Moreover you haven't used the fact that the radius is $3$ ; this can be done by expressing that the center of the circle whose coordinates are "visibly" $(x_1+L,y_1-\frac{L}{2})=(x_1+L,2x_1-\frac{L}{2})$ is at distance $3$ from $(x_1,y_1)=(x_1,2x_1)$ ; this condition is expressed by

$$L^2+\frac{L^2}{4}=3^2 \ \implies \ L=\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{5}}\tag{3}$$

(The plus sign has been chosen in order to have the center of the circle under the line with equation $y=2x$ ; we could have as well chosen to determine $M=-3\sqrt{2}$).

$L$ being known, system (2) is reduced to 3 simple equations with 3 unknowns.

In this way your method is fully viable.

Remark: the third equation in (2) expresses the equality of the lengths of the tangents $OT_1$ and $OT_2$ issued from the origin.

---

**Here is a different way**. Let $C=(x_0,y_0)$ be the center of the circle.

The different constraints of distances can be encapsulated into the double equation (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/85761)):

$$\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(y_0-x_0)}_{\text{distance from C to line } y-x=0}=\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(2x_0-y_0)}_{\text{distance from C to line } y-2x=0} \ = \ \ 3$$

whose solution is

$$x_0=3(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}), \ \ y_0=3(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5})$$

Therefore, the equation of your circle is:

$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=3^2$$

that can be somewhat simplified if you expand the squares.

Comment: Could you comment my solutions ? Are they understandable ?

Comment: Yes the solution is clear, my approach was correct but it got lengthy

Comment: This method is not classicaly taught. I m curious to know if your intructor has given you explanations about "pencils of circles" ?

Comment: This is an IIT JEE problem I was trying method different from solutions provided in the website. The best method is angular bisector method

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. "The best method", generally speaking for competitive exams, is an elusive concept. It may be the best because you are on limited time, but not the best because too particular, too difficult to check in case of an error, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a better approach. You have been given the lines $y=x$ and $y=2x$. You should just consider coordinates of centre of circle to be $(h,k)$, and then simply write the equation of perpendicular distance from a point on a line, for both given lines. This will give you two relations to solve, thus you get centre's coordinates. While solving be careful to note that centre must lie above $y=x$ but below $y=2x$.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to first put the circle at the origin. Then find where tangent lines of the given slopes interesect, and shift from there.

The circle $x^2+y^2=9$ has tangent lines at $(x,y)$ with slope $-\frac{x}{y}$. So the slope $1$ tangent line is tangent at some $(a,-a)$. So $2a^2=9$, and $a=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$. The point is $\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

The slope $2$ tangent line is tangent at some $(-2b,b)$. So $5b^2=9$, and $b=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}$. The point is $\left(\frac{-6}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$.

So the two lines are
$$\begin{align}
y&=(x-3/\sqrt{2})-\frac{3}{\sqrt2}=x-\frac{6}{\sqrt2}\tag{EQ1}\\
y&=2(x+6/\sqrt{5})+\frac{3}{\sqrt5}=2x+\frac{15}{\sqrt{5}}\tag{EQ2}
\end{align}$$

Solve that system to find where the lines intersect:
$$\left(\text{EQ2}-\text{EQ1}\,\text{to find }x,2\text{EQ1}-\text{EQ2}\,\text{to find }y \right)$$
$$\left(-\frac{15}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{6}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{15}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{12}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

So with the original question, shift by the negative of the above to get the center:
$$\left(\frac{15}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{6}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{15}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{12}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$